# qmake Language reserved word issue (I think)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qmake

To give a little context, I'm in the business of packing an executable with static plugins (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins).

In Windows, I do:

```
LIBS           = -L../../plugins -lrawplugin
LIBS           = -L../../plugins -lbasictools

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release)
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
```

The `if` statement takes care of adding the letter `d` to the library name just in debug mode, where the file name is `librawplugind.a` for example.

On Mac OS, libraries are named i.e. `libbasictools_debug.a`, so I was thinking I would just replace `d` with `debug` in the `if` statement:

```
if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release)
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)debug
```

But it didn't worked. I guess because `debug` is a reserved word in the qmake language.

How to overcome this issue?

I think this is similar to the problem of printing `"` in `qDebug() << "\"";`, where `"` must be preceded by `\`.

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qmake syntax does not know the "if". Simply use:

```
!debug_and_release|build_pass:CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
}
```